# Stopping BGSOUND element on IE?

Tags: javascript, html, background-music

I've added background music to a website i'm building (don't kill me). 
Whereas in IE the element is called BGSOUND, I tried to have a button to pause 
the music, the button removes the entire element and re-adds it, however 
turns out removing the element only restarts the music for IE.

How do I stop music being played by the BGSOUND element via javascript?

Current code:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <BGSOUND id="bgmusic" SRC="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/bgmusic.mp3" LOOP="true">
<![endif]-->
```

When I fire the command `document.getElementById('bgmusic').stop()` 
I get *Object doesn't support property or method 'stop'*

Comment: I'd still want to kill you for using <BGSOUND>, provided that you have no control on putting a background music at all =))

Comment: that's why I want to know the command for stopping it - to create a control... Don't blame the developer, blame the client ;)

Comment: Indeed: the [`bgSound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object doesn't have a `stop` method.

Comment: I blame the developer. The client doesn't know any better, you should. Instead of doing whatever the client asks, propose a better solution.

Comment: Not an answer, because this is just speculation, but have you tried putting the bgsound elment inside a iframe, then on stop, destroying the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Flash instead. Not only will you have more control over the music, but it will work across browsers too. Today more users have [Flash player](http://www.statowl.com/flash.php) than [IE](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0).

Comment: how do I embed an mp3 file using flash player? any short way of doing that?

Comment: Now that you asked, this is plain awesomeness: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Thumbs up, looks good! I've never had to do sound in my webpages, but this certainly looks promising!

Answer (score 3):

An ugly work around is by setting the [`volume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535140%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to -10000:

```
document.getElementById('bgmusic').volume = -10000;
```

Comment: this answer save me too! thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation with the page of a client.
I found that [removing the src property](http://mrelbow.com/how-to-stop-all-background-sound-on-page-change/) of the bgsound elements is the best way to avoid the restart music problem in IE.

```
var bgsoundElems = document.getElementsByTagName('bgsound');
for(var i = 0; i < bgsoundElems.length; i++){
   bgsoundElems[i].src = '';
}
```

Comment: thanks man, this what i need, big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When user presses `Pause`: Remove the element and store it in a variable
When user presses `Play` : Get the element from the variable and add it to the DOM

Comment: upon removing the element, music simply restarts, but doesn't stop

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

It will use HTML5 audio when it can, and will otherwise fall back to Flash. And it has a [unified and easy API](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a stop(), you can just set src to an empty value. Works in IE11 (with IE8 emulation as well).