# HTML5 <audio> tag not working in IE11: "Origin is not valid"

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-11, shoutcast

I have an HTML5 `<audio>` tag which is working well in IE9, Chrome, Mozilla and Safari. However, in IE11 it is not working and shows the message:

> Origin is not valid

This is an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: We don't have access to your Gmail account so your image isn't working. How about posting the actual code? :-)

Comment: Sorry, this is an other link http://fusionglobalfx.com/Captura.PNG and the url of the page is : www.energiafm.com.ec, please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE bug Invalid Source HTML5 audio - workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213302/ie-bug-invalid-source-html5-audio-workaround)